# Windows 10 hard capping max processor use

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cpu

My laptop is a HP Pavilion Notebook with an Intel Core i5-6200U, integrated Intel HD Graphics 520 and Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 19041). Something really odd has been happening to me for a while: Sometimes my laptop will just cap the use on the processor, effectively hard-capping the FPS on any of the games I play to 30 FPS, the thing is that this doesn't always happen, it has been happening for almost a year now, from what I've seen when I turn on my laptop sometimes it will be in this "capped" state (the only way for me to know is to open a game and check) and it be like that until I reset or completely shutdown and turn on again. It is worth noting that my drivers are up to date, and every time I see I'm in this capped state I check all the config related to power saving, just to see that all the options are the same as in the "uncapped" state. Another detail is that in this capped state the max temperature the processor can reach is 60 °C (the fan is always silent) while playing, in the uncapped state it can reach up to 74 °C and you can clearly hear the fan anytime it goes above 62 °C

Comment: can you determine the CPU frequency while capped and uncapped? you can use tools like CPUz or speccy or coretemp to see your current frequency. the laptop will adjust your frequency based on thermal and power considerations. you do have some control over it with the windows advanced power configuration settings.

Comment: The frequency while capped is around 2300 MHz, in uncapped mode is 2700 MHz. In power settings the processor max use is 100%. There is a setting called Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework settings, but it only has 1 option which is 15.0W @ 2.1GHz

Comment: ok so dynamic frequency scaling is definitely the issue then. Poke through your BIOS/Firmware and see if there are any options for your specific laptop. Also I encourage you to contact HP support. I've had to have them give me links to special versions of the firmware before to resolve issues with adding ram or access to virtualization settings. Good luck!